# How to parse a symbolic expression in Matlab

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

In Matlab 2016a, Mathworks deprecated the use of the `sym` function for parsing symbolic expressions:

```
>> expr = sym('x + 1')
Warning: Support of strings that are not valid variable names or define a number will be
removed in a future release. To create symbolic expressions, first create symbolic
variables and then use operations on them. 
> In sym>convertExpression (line 1536)
  In sym>convertChar (line 1441)
  In sym>tomupad (line 1198)
  In sym (line 177) 

expr =

x + 1
```

The warning's suggestion is not practical when the symbolic expressions are being read from a file rather than built by hand in code. Is there a function in Matlab to replace this functionality? I would rather not `regexprep` and `eval` my way through it.

Comment: Do you want to parse arbitrary expressions or just functions?

Comment: It may be worth contacting MathWorks support with your specific use case. Note that one of the reasons why the input above is deprecated is that inside these strings, you have to use MuPAD syntax, not MATLAB, which makes, e.g., the output of `sym('zeta(a,b)')` a little unexpected to many users.

Comment: @Matt My most common use-case is simple expressions `2*x+y^2+1`. Sometimes I will use function calls `sin(x)` in the expression.

Comment: Where do these "symbolic expressions are being read from a file" come from? Can you rewrite whatever produces them to generate an M-file that includes lines that define all of your variables with `sym`/`syms` and create named expressions, i.e., `f1 = 2*x+y^2+1`? Maybe this is an X-Y problem? – if you share a bit about what you're actually doing, we might be able to propose a better solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Matlab 2017b, the [`str2sym`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/str2sym.html) function was added to replace the lost functionality of parsing a string into a symbolic expression. It works essentially like `sym` used to:

```
>> expr = str2sym('x + 1')

expr =

x + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

This syntax was originally deprecated in R2015b ([archived documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2015b/symbolic/sym.html)), though it has been clear that it was going to happen for many years. The warning has been added in R2016a. Who knows when this functionality will be fully removed.

You don't want to use `eval`, but that's effectively what the current symbolic engine uses when you pass it string expressions. Even after this syntax is removed, there will likely still be [ways to call the MuPAD engine](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/calling-mupad-functions-from-matlab.html) like this:

```
f1 = evalin(symengine,'2*x+y^2+1')
```

One "workaround" is of course to disable the [`warning`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/warning.html) in R2016a:

```
S = warning('off','MATLAB:singularMatrix'); % Change second string to correct MsgID
... % Do stuff
warning(S); % Reset warning state
```

Answer (score -2):

Check out this line from the Mathworks site on [sym and syms](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/sym.html): (my  emphasis in bold)

> To create symbolic expressions, first create symbolic variables, and then use operations on them. **For example, use syms x; x + 1 instead of sym('x + 1')**  ...

There are several other examples after that, though this one speaks very exactly to your question. I'm not sure if that'll be compatible with the file you're reading. Hopefully so! Let me know if not, happy to try helping with any potential followup.

Comment: Did you even read his question? He explicitly states that this is not practical: `The warning's suggestion is not practical when the symbolic expressions are being read from a file`

Comment: How do you place the expression in the code? I guess the OP knows how to do it by writing the lines in the console/script. He asks for a way to *parse* it while running. So he needs a method translating a string to the corresponding symbolic expression.